# Facebook SDK to get user pictures

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am new to swift and trying to learn how to read data from facebook using SDK.

Here are the code which I added:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {
            // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
            println("User is already logged in")
        }
        else
        {
            let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            self.view.addSubview(loginView)
            FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
            loginView.center = self.view.center
            loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_photos"]
            loginView.delegate = self
        }

    }


 func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        println("User Logged In")
        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            // Handle cancellations
        }
        else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
            {
                println("\(result.grantedPermissions)")
                // Do work
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run my application xcode simulator gives following warning:
"Some of the permissions below have not been approved by facebook" and it gives me option of submitting it for review. Is it because I am trying to get read permission for "user_photos"? I am trying to read user public profile as well as all the public pictures. Please let me know what should be my next steps to achieve the above.

Comment: You have to submit your app for review on Facebook before you can use this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com) create Application and In setting tab fill up Contact Email and bundle id for app same as your app and In Status and review tab make "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" to YES.

Now you will get permission for email,public profile and user friends

Comment: Hi Bhoomi - thanks for your reply. I cannot change the status to yes as it says my app is not live. Do I have to give my app for review if I need more then email,public profile and user friends? I am just trying to do this for my education purposes. Is their no other way?

Answer (score 1):

In order to let your iOS app work together with facebook, you have to create a Facebook app and link it with your iOS app.
Here is the [facebook developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) explaning all you need to use it.